# Developer Console Test Logs: Unable to Access Page

Tags: unit-test, developer-console

As I'm running the debugger I am attempting to review the execution logs from past test-executions that have completed, however, when I click the class in the `Test` tab of the *Developer Console* I get a small pop-out page with: 'Unable to Access Page' error.

Furthermore, I only get one execution log in the `Logs` tab unless I reopen the Developer Console and re-run my test!? Sometimes a log doesn't even display!

This issue seems to be relatively recent *Summer '15* release?

[image]

Comment: Can you see the logs in /setup/ui/listApexTraces.apexp or with a SOQL query against [ApexLog](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apexlog.htm)? Neither of these would fix anything, but might indicate if the problem is specific to the developer console.

Comment: I was able to resolve similar issue by enabling the debug logs for my user in the ui.

Comment: @zokito Can you be more specific? Like adding a user to the `Monitored User` list? `Setup > Debug Logs`?

Comment: @jordan.baucke yes exactly that way.

Comment: @jordan.baucke did that resolve the issue?